# Update input label which is render by array map in REACTJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hope you guys are fine.

I have the next code for dynamically show the quantity of each selected product

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import db from '../firebase';
//const Swal = window.Swal;

const NewSale = () => {

const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
const [selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    if(products.length === 0){
        db.collection('products').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            const docs = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

                docs.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                });

            });

            docs.sort((a, b)=> a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

            setProducts(docs);
        });
    }
});

const handleSelectChange = (e) => {

    const value = e.target.value;

    if(value){

        const selectedProduct = products.filter(item => item.id === value)[0];

        setSelectedProducts(selectedProducts => [...selectedProducts, {
            id: value,
            name: selectedProduct.name,
            quantity: 1
        }]);
    }
    
}

const handleRangeChange = (target, index) => {

    const currentValue = parseInt(target.value);

    let currentArrayValue = selectedProducts;

    currentArrayValue[index].quantity = currentValue;

    setSelectedProducts(currentArrayValue);
}

const handleCancelButton = () => {
    setSelectedProducts([]);
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div className='container'>
            <h1 className='display-3 text-center'>New Sale</h1>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col'>
                    <div className='mb-3'>
                        <label htmlFor='product' className='form-label fs-3'>Service</label>
                        <select id='product' onChange={handleSelectChange} className='form-select form-select-lg' multiple aria-label='multiple select service'>
                            {products.length !== 0?
                                products.map(item => <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>) : <option>No product registered</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='row mt-4'>
                <div className='col'>
                    <table className='table caption-top'>
                        <caption>Sell List</caption>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope='col'>#</th>
                                <th scope='col'>Product</th>
                                <th scope='col'>Quantity</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {selectedProducts.length !== 0?
                                selectedProducts.map((item, index) => (
                                    <tr key={index}>
                                        <th scope='row'>{(index + 1)}</th>
                                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label htmlFor={`customRange-${index}`} className='form-label'>{item.quantity} Units</label>
                                            <input
                                                type='range'
                                                className='form-range'
                                                value={item.quantity}
                                                onChange={({target}) => handleRangeChange(target, index)}
                                                min='1'
                                                max='100'
                                                step='1'
                                                id={`customRange-${index}`}/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )) :
                                <tr>
                                    <th className='text-center' colSpan='3'>Nothing selected!</th>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='row mt-2'>
                <div className='col'>
                    <button className='btn btn-success'>Save</button>
                </div>
                <div className='col'>
                    <button className='btn btn-warning' onClick={handleCancelButton}>Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
)
};

export default NewSale;
```

The code shows this... I do not know if I'm allowed to do this kind of operations because I'm adding events every time I select a product so, I'm not sure this is the best way to do it.

[image]

And the problem is that I'm getting this unexpected result,
[image]

What I want to do is show the current Quantity for each selected item,

Thanks!!

Comment: show code instead image

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the problem, but every input element has the same id. You should make them unique, such as by adding the index to the id name.

Comment: Got it, now you have the code and thanks Irv Kats, didn't notice it